# What do doubled-verb-doubled-noun and doubled-noun-doubled-noun constructions imply?

Tags: doubled-words

In the sentence "The company is able to store and conserve fruits and vegetables.", which relations between verbs and nouns exactly do we imply?

Let's consider the following general case "**A and B** **C and D**", where A and B are verbs and C and D are nouns, e.g. "store and conserve fruits and vegetables".

Intuitively, it seems that *both* A and B apply to *both* C and D. However, is this always the case? Do we have to make use of the word *both*, e.g. "The company is able to store and conserve *both* fruits and vegetables."? Is it acceptable to use this construction if we want both A and B to apply to C and B to D, but A not to D, for instance if the combination A and D does not make sense? Example: "to eat and store food and energy", where "eat energy" does not make sense. Is this acceptable, or how would this example have to be tweaked to obtain an acceptable construction?

Secondly, what happens if we use different tenses or nouns instead of verbs? Do we make the same implications, or does something change? Example:

- "The company stores and conserves fruits and vegetables."
- "The company is storing and conserving fruits and vegetables."
- "The company is into storage and conservation of fruits and vegetables."

Especially for the latter (where we have replaced verbs with nouns) I am tempted to make use of the word *both*, twice, if I want to imply all relations: 
"The company is into *both* storage and conservation of *both* fruits and vegetables."

Lastly, let me note that I'm not sure if I'm on the right SE, because this question also applies to many other languages.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you are making this far too complicated.

> The company is able to store and conserve fruits and vegetables.

The obvious and intuitive meaning in this case is that both verbs apply to both nouns. If you want to change that, all you have to do is change the position of a couple of words..

*The company is able to store fruits and conserve vegetables.*

The same is true regardless of tense.

> We eat and store food and energy.

In this case the implication (among others) is that we eat energy. Now we have to ask what you are really trying to say. There are several possibilities:

*(a)  We eat food and store energy.*

*(b) We eat food and store both food and energy.*

*(c) something else.*

(a) is already clear.

For (b), you have had to repeat 'food' but it doesn't seem clumsy. In fact that's how it would usually be said. The use of 'both' adds emphasis but it is not really needed.

Let me know if option (c) applies.

EDIT

You may be interested in the use of the word 'respectively'. I don't think it is needed here but it is relevant.

> Definition of **respectively** in English:   respectively adverb
>
> Separately or individually and in the order already mentioned (used
>   when enumerating two or more items or facts that refer back to a
>   previous statement):  ‘they received sentences of one year and eight
>   months respectively’
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respectively)